# How to Remove Unnecessary Services from Folder Menu in macOS Sonoma?

Tags: services, sonoma

After updating to macOS Sonoma, my folder context menu is cluttered with many services I don't use.

How can I remove these unnecessary services?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can untick the ones you don't want in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts... -> Services.

[image]
[image]